# Ограничить количество post запросов

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть код:

```
<script>

    var clickedButtonValue;

    $('button[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        clickedButtonValue = $(this).val();
    });



    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("#commentadd").submit(function(event) {

        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault();

        /* get some values from elements on the page: */
        var $form = $(this),
                text = $form.find('textarea[id="userComment"]').val(),
                number = $form.find('input[id="num_clear"]').val(),
                url = $form.attr('action'),
                term = clickedButtonValue;



        /* Send the data using post */
        var posting = $.post(url, {
            like: term,
            text: text,
            num_clear: number
        });

        posting.done(function( data )
        {
            /* Put the results in a div */
            var data1 = $(data).find("#comments");
            var data2 = $(data).find("#getrating");

            $( "#comments" ).html(data1);
            $( "#getrating" ).html(data2);
            $("#commentadd")[0].reset();
        });





    });




</script>
```

Нужно ограничить отправку post запроса при клике на кнопку не чаще, чем раз в 5 секунд.

Comment: Может стоит использовать куку или сессию? Сохраните в куке кол-во выполненных запросов, время клика последнего, другие параметры связанные с этим событием.

Comment: С куки на заметку взял еще в начале. Но хочется реализовать именно на javascript ограничение. Не учитывать клик на submit чаще, чем раз в 5 секунд.

Comment: Обработка кукисов итак происходит на javascript. Ну тогда создайте переменную и внесите в нее значение, по истечении 5 секунд обнулите. Скрипт отправляющий пост-запрос должен проверить значение переменной, обнулено - отправит, иначе - нет.

Comment: Делал, как указано здесь http://stackoverflow.com/a/5031515/3993065, но в таком варианте почему-то ajax отправка перестает работать и отправке посылает на страницу обработчик.

Comment: Я у вас в коде не вижу кода из примера вашей ссылки на англоязычный stackoverflow .

Comment: Здесь предоставил изначальный код. 

В if код с англ стака я просто оборачивал свой, начиная с `/* attach a submit handler to the form */`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задаем переменной `fire` значение `true` в начале работы скрипта. Перед `post` отправкой проверяем, если `fire = true`, выполняем `post`, задаем `fire = false` и вешаем таймер назначить `fire = true через 3 секунды`. Итоговый код:

```
<script>
        fire = true;

        var clickedButtonValue;

        $('button[type="submit"]').click(function() {
            clickedButtonValue = $(this).val();
        });



        /* attach a submit handler to the form */
        $("#commentadd").submit(function(event) {

            /* stop form from submitting normally */
            event.preventDefault();

            /* get some values from elements on the page: */
            var $form = $(this),
                    text = $form.find('textarea[id="userComment"]').val(),
                    number = $form.find('input[id="num_clear"]').val(),
                    url = $form.attr('action'),
                    term = clickedButtonValue;



            /* Send the data using post */
            if (fire = true) {
                fire = false;
                var posting = $.post(url, {
                    like: term,
                    text: text,
                    num_clear: number
                });

                setTimeout(function() {
                    fire = true;
                }, 3000);
            }
            posting.done(function( data )
            {
                /* Put the results in a div */
                var data1 = $(data).find("#comments");
                var data2 = $(data).find("#getrating");

                $( "#comments" ).html(data1);
                $( "#getrating" ).html(data2);
                $("#commentadd")[0].reset();
            });





        });


    </script>
```

Comment: true/false в текстовом виде, серьёзно что ли?

Comment: @Mr_Epic поменял)